# JQuery and multiple inputs,forms,submits

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms

I have a bunch of forms as rows in a table. There's a submit button at the end of each row. When this button is clicked, my JQuery function creates two text boxes and another submit button. I want the POST variables from the both forms, so I can ultimately pass it onto my php script via AJAX. What would be the best way of doing this?

```
<script>
<?php 
$ajax_var = <<<HTML
<form method="post" id="ajax_form">
<div id="ajax_input">
    <input type="text" name="user_name" placeholder="Your name">
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="user_email" placeholder="Your e-mail">
    <br>
</div>
    <input id="ajax_submit" type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
HTML;
$ajax_var = str_replace("\n",'',$ajax_var);
?>

$("form").submit(function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#wrapper").prepend('<?php echo "$ajax_var" ?>');
});
$("form#ajax_form").submit(function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
});
</script>
```

The last JQuery function does not work as intended. Pressing the ajax-created submit reloads the page :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `#ajax_form` is not present initially. you should use `.on`:

```
$("#wrapper").on("submit", "form#ajax_form", function(e) 
{
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("It is working...");
    // Your code for Ajax
});
```

You can use any element wrapping the new form, if not sure put `"body"` in stead of `"#wrapper"`.

**Documentation:** http://api.jquery.com/on/

Code Added as per communication in comments:

```
<script type="application/javascript">
var arr;
$(function(){
$("form").submit(function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#wrapper").prepend('<?php echo "$ajax_var" ?>');
    arr = $(this).serializeArray();
});
$("#wrapper").on("submit", "form#ajax_form", function(e)
{
    console.log(arr);
    e.preventDefault();
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: Nice! And how should I pass $_POST variables between the forms I have in my table to my new AJAX form?

Comment: You can use `form.serializeArray()` for both forms, it will return you data for all fields in array format.

Comment: Okay, and if I assign it to a variable, it will be preserved between events?

Comment: I tested it, and it went out of scope once the second event was called (ajax form).

Comment: prepare a fiddle please or show me your full code. how are you declaring variable, just show me 2 - 3 lines around that?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mcvryhr2/1/
Basically like that format. I'm trying to pass hidden field values that I get from my table, along with the AJAX textfield inputs as POST variables.

Comment: check new code in answer. `var arr` should be global variable instead of local one.

Comment: Great. Thanks for being so patient and following through with me.